# What happens when a variable is uninitialized?

Tags: java

In JAVA, lets say I fail to initialize a variable: **String message;** as compared to **String message = "";**

What happens under the hood? Has the problem got to do with how JAVA is layered on top of assembly language? Or, its just a human writing an if statement comparing the declaration and seeing that its not meeting the standard.

Comment: Compiler will complain on it's first use. See [§16 in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-16.html)

Comment: If it is a local variable, then the compiler will emit an error, once you try to use it, and refuse to compile your code. That is because that is defined in the Java Language Specification. On the other hand, *fields* (instance variables) are initialized with a default value (`false`, `0`, `0.0`, `'\0'` or `null`). What happens under to hood, may be implementation-specific, but this limitation is probably defined so that all variables always have a predictable value.

Comment: There's an enormous difference between `null` and `""`.

Answer (score 0):

from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable);

> Java does not have uninitialized variables. Fields of classes and objects that do not have an explicit initializer and elements of arrays are automatically initialized with the default value for their type (false for boolean, 0 for all numerical types, null for all reference types).[2] Local variables in Java must be definitely assigned to before they are accessed, or it is a compile error.

if it's a primitive type, it's initialized any way. otherwise you need to initialize it, it won't compile if you don't.